# SQL Multiple join from 2 table to 1

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I want to join from 2 table to 1. I have tried it multiple times but I can't figure out the correct code. The name 'Edvard Supica' which is the full_name from suser table I want to be on the place of User ID and in 1 record.

[image: how it looks like now']

```
SELECT w.*, m.vin AS 'workbook_vin'
FROM workbook w
LEFT JOIN machines m ON m.id = w.machine_id
            
UNION

SELECT w.*, s.full_name AS 'user_full_name'
FROM workbook w
LEFT JOIN suser s ON s.id = w.user_id
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)  [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're joining both `machines` and `susers` tables with the `workbook` table, you can do both `JOIN`s in the same query without needing to use `UNION`.

```
SELECT
    w.*,
    m.vin AS 'workbook_vin',
    s.full_name AS 'user_full_name'
FROM
    workbook w
    LEFT JOIN machines m ON m.id = w.machine_id
    LEFT JOIN suser s ON s.id = w.user_id
```